# C# ejecucion de tareas en segundo plano de forma dinamica

Tags: c#

tengo la siguiente duda.
Como hago para que el parametro que le estoy pasando a esta funcion, se adapte al delegado que se asigna a DoWork += ??
ya que el paramero es un string, necesito que el delegado cambie en base a ese string.

```
public static bool EjecutaTarea(string NombreTareaEjecutar)
        {
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker tarea = new BackgroundWorker();
                tarea.DoWork += NombreTareaEjecutar;
                tarea.RunWorkerCompleted += Terminado;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;            }
        }


        static void Tarea1(object obj, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

        }
        static void Tarea2(object obj, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

        }


        static void Terminado(object obj, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

        }
```

saludos

Comment: tienes razon, me estaba complicando mas de la cuenta. Gracias por el aporte. saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez mediante reflection podrias conseguirlo, pero yo no te lo recomendaría. Es mucho mas sencillo hacer un `switch (NombreTareaEjecutar){ case "Tarea1": tarea.DoWork+=Tarea1; break; ....`